# Is it possible to use mock location apps by end user to simulate user location in iOS apps?

Tags: ios, react-native, mock-location

I found a setting `enable mock location` in android phones which allows user to simulate location. But I didn't any such a setting in `iPhone`.

Since I am very new to app development, I just want to hear from experts of `iOS` app development that is it possible to simulate the location in `iPhones` by using mock location apps?

Answer (score 1):

First, connect your device and execute the project.

Then in debug area, there are few default locations. You can choose any of them:

[image]

In case you need to mock specific latitude, longtitue. Check this link to generate PGX file: https://www.gpxgenerator.com/#. Then selecting `Add GPS Exchange to Workspace` option

Comment: By any chance Can end user do location mocking in production?

Comment: @Mighty Maybe there are some tricks with jailbreak devices. I have researched and found this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBSXCdm5eEk). However, I don't recommend it.